# Should we have a simple markup for footnotes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Footnotes (sometimes they cross several pages) are very common in linguistic literature. Is there a suitable markup for it in Markdown and should we use it actively on this site? It would certainly add to the flavour of the place.

Answer (score 1):

As both a sometimes-prolix writer and user of LaTeX, I appreciate software that makes it easy to typeset footnotes.  But I don't think that such a thing is needed here.  Most (some might say all) answers won't benefit from footnotes.  It is possible to do footnotes manually if you really want, like this.<sup>1</sup>  So, I don't think we need special markup for this.

What's more, it looks like this feature request was already refused up by the SO developers: [see discussion here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes)

**Footnotes**

1. For example

Comment: Well, Stackovflow may not be wikipedia and in the need of footnes, but linguistics is even more footnote happy than wikipedia. A standardized markup might lead to it becoming a common sight. Though I don't think we'll be able to produce the sort of multi-page monsters I like to show my non-linguist techie friends even if we wanted to. That takes a skill-level of a Lovecraftian nature I doubt anybody here possess (yet). The slack-jawed deer-in-headlights sheer mindless terror as they point and gibber and scream "fooooour paaaages?!" is a sight to behold.